# How do i resize the layout to fit every screen size in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, storyboard

What I want is if I design for iPad retina 1024 x 768 when someone use the app on iPad Pro or smaller size iPad all the elements should resize and fit the screen size. I don't want my layout to look smaller on bigger screen size or bigger on smaller screen size. How do I achieve it?

**What I'm doing right now is**

```
func getWidthfromConstantForScreenSize(constant: CGFloat, size: CGFloat = 1024, cSize: CGFloat = screenSize.width) -> CGFloat {
    return cSize * (constant / size) // It returns the new size for the screen
}
func getHeightfromConstantForScreenSize(constant: CGFloat, size: CGFloat = 768, cSize: CGFloat = screenSize.height) -> CGFloat {
    return cSize * (constant / size) // It returns the new size for the screen
}
```

**But it's a big task for doing for every element any one know's how to achieve it easily?**

I'm using autolayout but i still have to resize programmatically.

Comment: Can you clarify what these elements are? 'Normal' GUI elements will resize automatically using autolayout if your constraints are correct.

Comment: you can use autolayout programmtically as well

Comment: @AliBeadle everything it may be UILabel or UIButton

Comment: @GopeshGupta  yeah I know but i like designing layout using storyboard

Comment: @AliBeadle normal GUI

Comment: Use UIStackView https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/index.html

Comment: You can set IBOutlet to constraints and then you can change them when you want according to screen size. In this way, you can do it programmatically by checking screen size.

Comment: @GopeshGupta im already doing that

Comment: @O-mkar OK, then autolayout should have very thing you need without having to do it programatically. Perhaps ask another question asking specifically what you want to do under autolayout?

Comment: @AliBeadle whatever you are telling is for simple layout for complex layout you have to do it programmatically

Comment: @O-mkar I am not sure I agree, but it depends on what you mean by complex I guess :) You can certainly make the UILabels and UIButtons referred to in your previous comment resize without additional code and I have many reasonably complex views resizing quite satifactorily for iPad and iPhone using auto layout and IB alone.